# R version 3.2.4 dump() not generating a file in working directory

Tags: r

From rStudio console I run this expression:

```
dump(c("X","Y"),file="dd.R")
```

I expect to see a file called dd.R in my working directory.  But this file is not showing.  Am I missing something here?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?  What is your working directory?

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered it:
X and Y should be other objects...

so this works:

```
x<-"X"
y<-"Y"
dump(c("x","y"),file="dd.R")
```